# UITableViewCell custom selectedBackgroundView background is transparent

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following code that creates a `UIView` that I assign to my `UITableViewCell`'s `selectedBackgroundView` property. Everything works as expected, with the exception of the subview's background, which is transparent.

I use the same code to create a custom view that I assign to `backgroundView`, and that works fine.

What is causing that subview to be transparent for `selectedBackgroundView`, and how can I avoid that?

```m
- (UIView*) makeSelectedBackgroundView
{
    // dimensions only for relative layout
    CGRect containerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);

    UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame];
    containerView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    // dimensions only for relative layout
    CGRect subframe = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 30);
    UIView* subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subframe];

    subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    subview.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    subview.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    subview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    [containerView addSubview:subview];

    return containerView;
}
```

Comment: can you add a picture with what you get and one with what you would expect?

Comment: have you tried to play with alpha? [subview setAlpha:0.0] for the subview.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I ended up subclassing UITableViewCell which contained a custom view object, and that worked.

Answer (score 7):

As we can see from name of ivar selectedBackgroundView, this background shown by cell when it was selected.
I've to reload few methods (**– setSelected:animated:** and **– setHighlighted:animated:**) of UITableViewCell subclass to reset background color of subviews back to their values. Look's like UIKit do some `magic` in this template methods (iterating over all UIView subclasses and set their background to **clearColor**)

Comment: This appears to be correct. I've managed to get the subview to show up by using a UIImageView to show an image. This image property does not get cleared like the background color.

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful for you:

```
UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                                         0, 
                                                      cell.frame.size.width, 
                                                      cell.frame.size.height
                                                         )];

  cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  // normal background view
  [cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"*<ImageName>*"]];

  [cell addSubview:cellImageView];
  [cell sendSubviewToBack:cellImageView];

  [cellImageView release], cellImageView = nil;
```

Here `cell` is an object of custom `UITableViewCell`.

Also you can set `backgroundColor` property.

Comment: Is this code not working at you end? If you find anyone's ans correct then plz mark is as accepted.

Comment: I can see how this would work, but I haven't tried it yet. Is there a way to do it without adding an additional subview to the cell?

Comment: This doesn't quite work. I'm also already setting backgroundColor, and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the alpha for both containerView and subView to 1.0

```
[containerView setAlpha:1.0];
...
[subview setAlpha:1.0];
```

this should make your controls totally opaque.

You could also create some images for the background and use that images in state of creating 2 views. Let's say you create 2 image (normalBackground.png and selectedBackground.png) and then set this images as cell background. [Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is a nice tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Try `setOpaque:YES` on your views.